# Validar CEP e preencher campos automaticamente jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Como posso validar um CEP e preencher um campo, por exemplo o da cidade, usando o jquery validate?

Por exemplo: o campo (input) que o usuário preencheria a cidade ficaria "disabled" e o valor do mesmo seria pego por uma validação do CEP, achei [este serviço gratuito](https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/) que retorna uma saída JSON sobre a informação do CEP.

Comment: validar o cep é facil, depende um pouco se vai ter - ou noa, mas basicamente são 8 numeros entao algo assim ja resolve `/^\d{8}$/.test('01001000')`. Depois você faz uma consulta nesse serviço e usa os dados do retorno para preencher o form. Tem algum ponto especifico que ta  tendo dificuldade?

Comment: Na verdade, a validação seria se o valor do CEP "batesse" com o retorno do JSON, e daí preencheria os campos, estou usando o plugin Jquery Validate.

Answer (score 2):

Para validar você pode usar um *regex*.

```
^\d{5}-\d{3}$
```

E para preencher os campos você pode utilizar um código neste estilo.

```js
var json={ 
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
};

for(key in json)
{
  if(json.hasOwnProperty(key))
    $('input[name='+key+']').val(json[key]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="cep"/>
  <input type="text" name="logradouro"/>
  <input type="text" name="bairro"/>
  <input type="text" name="localidade"/>
  <input type="text" name="uf"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas como seria isso feito com o plugin Jquery Validate?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 desculpa, não me atentei o principal fator (Jquery Validate). 
Caso você não obtenha uma resposta, posso tentar procurar depois e postar assim que eu obter uma resposta mais direta para você.